# One webhook for many Modules of custom Integromat app

Tags: make.com, integromat-apps

Is it possible to use one webhook in many instant triggers (modules)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. I have done that in the past unknowingly... and we had 2 scenarios triggered at the same time... In my case it was annoying :) So I ended up naming Integromat scenarios appending first or last 4 characters from webhook

"Integromat Scenario 1 h7dgf"

"Integromat Scenario 2 h7dgf"

So that they are easily and quickly searchable if I am not sure.

We have like 500 integromat scenarios and just having folders wasn't enough.